# Какая разница между типами данных TINYBLOB, TINYTEXT и VARCHAR в sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Привет.

Вопрос по типам данных в `sql`. `TINYBLOB`, `TINYTEXT` – тип данных `BLOB` или TE`X`T, максимальная длина 255 символов. чем они отличаются между собой? Есть еще `VARCHAR` - максимальная длина 255 символов. То есть, есть ТРИ варианта символьного типа данных с длиной до 255 символов (`TINYBLOB, TINYTEXT и VARCHAR` ). какая между ними разница. все три типа - символьные (до 255 символов) и все переменной длины.

Answer (score 4):

Судя по этой статье из доков http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html, есть разница в хранении между `VARCHAR` и `TINYBLOB`/`TINYTEXT`:

> Для хранения `VARCHAR(М)`:
>
> Если `M <= 255`, нужно `L + 1` байт для хранения данных.
>
> Если `M > 255`, нужно `L + 2` байта для хранения данных.
>
> Для хранения `TINYBLOB/TINYTEXT` нужно `L + 1` байт, но всегда `L <= 255` символов (`L < 2^8`), то есть длина строки строго ограничена.
>
> `L` - реальная длина строки

Разница же между `TINYBLOB` и `TINYTEXT` в способе хранения - первые хранятся в бинарном формате, а вторые как ASCII.

Так же, есть отличия в выделение памяти. Если не ошибаюсь, под `VARCHAR(M)` будет выделена память под все `M` символов, тогда как под `TINYBLOB`/`TINYTEXT` память будет выделяться динамически.

Если я правильно понимают, то если, к примеру, мы положим текст `"текст"` в `VARCHAR(255)` и в `TINYTEXT`/`TINYBLOB`.

**UPD:**

То при обработке под `VARCHAR(255)` будет выделено `255 * K + 1` байт в памяти , а под `TINYTEXT/TINYBLOB` - `L * K + 1` байт памяти.
**Здесь `K` - байт на символ**

Почему `К`, а не просто байты? Длина текста в байтах может зависеть от кодировки. **Небольшое демо**:

```
CREATE TABLE `tests`.`test` (
    `TB_` TINYBLOB, 
    `TT_UTF` TINYTEXT CHARACTER SET utf8, 
    `VC_255_UTF` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8, 
    `TT_CP1251` TINYTEXT CHARACTER SET cp1251, 
    `VC_255_CP1251` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET cp1251,
    `TT_UTF_16` TINYTEXT CHARACTER SET utf16 , 
    `VC_255_UTF_16` TINYTEXT CHARACTER SET utf16 , 
) ENGINE = InnoDB;


INSERT INTO `tests`.`test` 
VALUES 
    ('текст','текст', 'текст', 'текст', 'текст', 'текст', 'текст'),
    ('длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст','длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст','длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст','длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст','длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст','длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст','длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст')
;

SELECT 
    `TB` as TEXT,
    LENGTH(`TB`) AS TB, 
    LENGTH(`TT_UTF`) AS TT_UTF, 
    LENGTH(`VC_255_UTF`) AS VC_255_UTF,
    LENGTH(`TT_CP1251`) AS TT_CP1251, 
    LENGTH(`VC_255_CP1251`) AS VC_255_aCP1251,
    LENGTH(`TT_UTF_16`) AS TT_UTF_16, 
    LENGTH(`VC_255_UTF_16`) AS VC_255_UTF_16
FROM 
    `test`
```

**Получим следующий результат:**

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+------------+-----------+----------------+-----------+---------------+
| TEXT                                                                        | TT_UTF | VC_255_UTF | TT_CP1251 | VC_255_aCP1251 | TT_UTF_16 | VC_255_UTF_16 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+------------+-----------+----------------+-----------+---------------+
| текст                                                                       |     10 |         10 |         5 |              5 |        10 |            10 |
| длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст                                   |     75 |         75 |        41 |             41 |        82 |            82 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+------------+-----------+----------------+-----------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

LENGTH(str): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_length

> Returns the length of the string str, measured in bytes. A multibyte
>   character counts as multiple bytes. This means that for a string
>   containing five 2-byte characters, LENGTH() returns 10, whereas
>   CHAR_LENGTH() returns 5.

Да, заметил еще одну неточность в вашем посте:

> `TINYBLOB`, `TINYTEXT` – тип данных `BLOB` или `TEXT`, максимальная длина 255 символов.

**Максимальная длина этих типов - не символы, а байты.**

Добавим еще данных в нашу тестовую таблицу

```
INSERT INTO `tests`.`test`  VALUES 
(
'длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст',
'длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст',
'длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст',
'длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст',
'длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст',
'длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст',
'длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст'
);
```

**Результат**

```
+---------------+-------+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
| TB            | текст | длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст | длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст,                            | TB            |
+---------------+-------+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
| TT_UTF        | текст | длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст | длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст,                            | TT_UTF        |
+---------------+-------+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
| VC_255_UTF    | текст | длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст | длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст | VC_255_UTF    |
+---------------+-------+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
| TT_CP1251     | текст | длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст | длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст | TT_CP1251     |
+---------------+-------+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
| VC_255_CP1251 | текст | длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст | длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст | VC_255_CP1251 |
+---------------+-------+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
| TT_UTF_16     | текст | длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст | длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст д                                         | TT_UTF_16     |
+---------------+-------+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
| VC_255_UTF_16 | текст | длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст | длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст длинный текст, текст д                                         | VC_255_UTF_16 |
+---------------+-------+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ. плюсанул. если положить в ячейку типа VARCHAR(255) "текст" , то будет выделено, по идее, 11 байт - 1 байт на указание длины, 5 символов русских (чтобы закодировать каждый символ кириллицы в utf-8 надо 2 байта)  - 5*2=10. VARCHAR(М) - М это максимальное число символом,  а не байт, насколько я правильно понимаю.

Comment: @Dimon, да, мой косяк. Дополнил ответ. Так же, в конце добавил немного инфы о хранении данных в TINYTEXT и TINYBLOB